# Javascript: Benefit of naming functions when assigning variables in an object?

Tags: javascript

I noticed people in my company like to name functions when assigning it to variables. What are the benefits when it works exactly the same without naming them?

```
function TargetingForm() {
  'use strict';

  this.setPristine = function setPristine() {
    ...
  }

  //vs

  this.setPristine = function() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: http://kangax.github.io/nfe/

Comment: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/19303923/218196

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to ensure the name of the function appears in stack traces when debugging (as opposed to showing up as "anonymous function").

However, many modern javascript engines can derive a useful name for stack traces even when the function is declared anonymously in an assignment expression such as in your second example.

Answer (score 3):

One thing that I can think of (if I am right!) is that you might need to call the function from itself (recursion).

For example you can do this:

```
function TargetingForm() {
  'use strict';

  this.setPristine = function setPristine() {
    // You can do this
    if (someConditionIsTrue) {
        setPristine();
    }
  }

  //vs

  this.setPristine = function() {
    // You can't do the same here!
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, you could simply call `this.setPristine()`. And in fact you *should*, as otherwise you're loosing the `this` context