# Javascript addEventListener and removeEventListener with partial function

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, partial-application

I want to create javascript function adds an event listener to a div such that when the div is clicked, it runs a function, and ensures that the div can only be clicked once. My function looks like this right now:

```
function clickOnce(divID,func){
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,2);
  functionToRun=partial(func,args);
  thisDiv=document.getElementById(divID);
  thisDiv.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);
    functionToRun();
  });
}
```

I have a working example in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qtzLhgr4/1/
 In the JSfiddle, when I click button 1 it says "button #2 clicked".

Answer (score 3):

You didn’t declare `functionToRun`, so it’s implicitly global. Declare it and `thisDiv`:

```
var functionToRun=partial(func,args);
var thisDiv=document.getElementById(divID);
```

Then start working in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), which will prevent these kinds of problems as well as stop you from using `arguments.callee`, which is the Wrong Way To Do Things:

```
thisDiv.addEventListener("click", function listener(e) {
    thisDiv.removeEventListener("click", listener);
    functionToRun();
});
```

(`e.target` was also incorrect; `this` would have been better.)

Comment: Good catch with `e.target`. `this` is the best solution, but one could also use `e.currentTarget`. `e.target` will break as soon as the element contains other elements.

Answer (score 2):

`functionToRun` (and `thisDiv`, but that's not related to the problem) is global. The second call to `clickOnce` overwrites `functionToRun`, so both event handlers execute the same function.

Always declare your variables. Also note that [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee) is deprecated. You can use a [named function expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19303923/218196) instead.

Comment: Except for when you can use `let`; then always use `let` ;) (Supported in IE11)

Comment: @Sampson: Prefer `const` =)